# lost swap and no idea why

Tags: swap

I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a DELL Inspiron 7. I was happily browsing away, when all of a sudden the laptop turned off as if someone unplugged the power. I reboot no problem, but I noticed, that I have lost my swap partition. It turned out the UUID changed. I have of course no idea when the swap was lost, but I haven't messed around with the partitions since install, so it is very-very unlikely it was me (unless a program I installed did something funny...). I would be interested if anybody has any idea, what could have happened.

As a small plus info, the `fstab` says swap was on `/dev/sda3` during install, now it's `sda5`.

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I was not exactly clear, I was able to solve the problem, I checked the UUID of the swap with `blkid` and changed it in `fstab`, and turned it on with `swapon` I was interested in if you have any ideas **why** it happened. I found out the problem when I saw that there's no swap and `swapon` reported that it can't find the given UUID.

I'll put the outputs here none the less, but they already show I fixed the problem itself. But I have no idea what caused it :(

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=4b8ca41f-91d9-4e30-8aa5-68a66862b5a8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=0E66-BECA  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=222b1759-950e-427a-8d07-3f463306c80f none            swap    sw              0       0

$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="90074de6-e2ec-4fa8-9e83-37985513e46d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="222b1759-950e-427a-8d07-3f463306c80f" TYPE="swap" 

$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition   16567292    280 -1

$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                 
├─sda1 ext4         /
├─sda4              
└─sda5 swap         [SWAP]
sr0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the content of `/etc/fstab` and the output of `swapon -s` and `sudo lsblk -f`. Then drop me a comment, so I can look at them. :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks, I added the stuff, I hope it helps telling why it happened, I found this very strange, that the UUID just changed out of the blue.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have no idea, why this happened. Unless it reoccurs, I'd consider it a fluke and wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command from a terminal window to make sure you still have a `swap` partition detected:

```
sudo blkid
```

You should see something similar to the following output:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Seagate Backup Plus Drive" UUID="6AAA4323AA42EB61" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="250GB_SHARE" UUID="240433A6043379BE" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd1: UUID="a58096e4-eb95-4d9c-baf1-116b9790f435" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdd3: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="3CE41D3EE41CFC38" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd4: UUID="7A0E25640E251B21" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd5: UUID="42f81964-fe1c-49bc-9b0a-2c5dde01071d" TYPE="swap"
```

As you can see my last line is what my swap partition is.  If you see that, and it is the same as in your `/etc/fstab` file, then type in from the terminal window:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

which will activate all swaps from the `/etc/fstab` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer! I edited the question so it is more clear, that I have already solved the symptom, I am more interested the cause of the situation (so maybe I can prevent it from happening again).